# How to Access and Update images from Appwrite in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, appwrite

I'm using a View frontend to pull a PDF file from Appwrite Storage. I want to get the PDF, add a few lines of text on it and then download it to the local device.

This is the code I have - I can get the response but don't know how to access/view it, make edits to it and download it to a user

```js
const promiseFile = storage.getFileView(
                "[BUCKET ID]",
                "[FILE ID]"
            )

console.log(promiseFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

AppWrite can actually help you achieve this goal but you'll need to approach it in a different way.

**The Process**

1. You'll need to [create a function](https://appwrite.io/docs/functions#gettingStarted) inside your AppWrite engine.
2. In the function and you can use Node, PHP, Dart, Python, and more to write the logic that will do the PDF manipulation.
3. At the end of the function return a download (see more on that in the end) link to the Vue instance.
4. Inside your Vue side redirect the user to the download link which contained the headers required for forcing file downloading.

**Direct URL to file**
In order to get a direct URL to a file, AppWrite has two methods inside the SDK that can help you to give a user direct access.

`download` - To generate a download link create a link as follow:

```
https://your-app-write/v1/storage/buckets/[BUCKET]/files/[FILE]/download?project=[PROJECT_ID]
```

`view` - To generate a viewable (direct access) link as follow:

```
https://your-app-write/v1/storage/buckets/[BUCKET]/files/[FILE]/download?project=[PROJECT_ID]
```